# Regarding dark energy/matter calculations

Tags: cosmology, dark-matter, dark-energy

Dark energy/matter is assumed to exist based on calculations that don't include terms for radiation energy in transit thru the system under consideration. Could the energy in transit thru a given system which is not detectable (orthogonal) by line of  sight to the detector (telescopes either ground or space based) make up the difference and account for this "dark energy/matter"?

Comment: I don't understand your question, in particular why it matters that something is "orthogonal", or what "energy in transit" means.

Comment: I think I get your point but that radiation is taken into account as energy density.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal cosmological models do take the radiation contents (e.g. starlight and the CMB) into account when they fit data. It is dealt with in standard textbooks (e.g. Ryden's *Introduction to Cosmology*). It is a common lead-up to explaining how to treat different source terms in the Friedmann equations.

Given that energy is a smaller component than visible matter ([the current benchmark inventory](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0406095) is 0.2% of the visible matter mass), it cannot be an explanation for dark matter observations. Radiation-dominated universes would be very hot and it would be very obvious if there was enough radiation to change galactic rotation curves and cause gravitational lensing since it would be hitting things rather intensely.

Energy in the form of non-interacting modes, something like neutrinos, might seem viable instead. But the simulations of structure formation favour cold dark matter models, that is, dark matter that is moving non-relativistically. Without it, you don't get the cosmic web structure we observe.

Comment: How does energy density factor in the energy of EM propogation that is orthogonal to our detectors line of sight? If this density value is based on what can be detected via line of sight then it surely there is an problem......

Comment: @RaSullivan - We do not seem to be in an exceptional location where there is a lot of energy passing us by without hitting us (such locations likely do not exist since energy from most processes tends to be emitted in random directions). So the total amount of energy reaching us from different directions gives a good estimate of the amount of energy there is elsewhere.